# How to enable scroll for div which is shown when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have div which is shown when clicked on a button in navbar. The div's height is more than the view port/page. I want to enable scroll for the page when the div is shown.

I tried with `overflow: scroll` but it didn't work. The scroll is getting applied to internal div which is shown on button click but I want to apply to page when clicked. How do I work this?

Plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/JzGCix39dSd1q7KOiNTc?p=preview

Code:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
              <a href="#" id="showKoo" onclick="showKoo()">Tool bar</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="mainBorder topcorner complete_width complete_height" id="box" style="display: block; background-color:red">
      <h4> SOME CONTENT</h4>
    </div>
  </body>
```

css:

```
body{
  overflow: scroll;
}

.centered_div{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.mainBorder{
    border: 1px #B2B9BA solid;
    overflow:scroll;
}

.topcorner{
    position:fixed;
    top:41px;
    right:30px;
}

.complete_width {
    min-width: 360px;
    max-width: 360px;
}

.complete_height {
    min-height:640px;
    max-height:640px;
}
```

js:

```
function showKoo() {
    $('#box').toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to mention overflow for body. It'll append scroll based on the content.

Try position:absolute instead of fixed.

```js
// Code goes here

function showKoo() {
    $('#box').toggle();
}
```

```css
/* Styles go here */


body{
  position:relative;
}

.centered_div{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.mainBorder{
    border: 1px #B2B9BA solid;
    
}

.topcorner{
    position:absolute;
    top:41px;
    right:30px;
}

.complete_width {
    min-width: 360px;
    max-width: 360px;
}

.complete_height {
    min-height:640px;
    max-height:640px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.1" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
              <a href="#" id="showKoo" onclick="showKoo()">Tool bar</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="mainBorder topcorner complete_width complete_height" id="box" style="display: block; background-color:red">
      <h4> SOME CONTENT</h4>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Body will normally take the height of its content. UNLESS you mess with the positioning of any child elements.

In this case, your box has "position: fixed", due to ".topcorner".

This is popping it out of the normal flow of the document, causing body to not take it's height into consideration.

Do you really need position: fixed on that element?